# Getting Isolated storage path with inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to get the isolated storage path from de [code] section of inno setup.
I have tried using {userappdata} and {commonappdata} constants, buth without success.
My purpose is during installation, copy some files in the isolated Storage folder.
Someone who knows how can I do it?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Isolated storage of what (which application) ? What is your aim behind this ?

Comment: Hi. well, I'm trying to make an installer to burn it into a CD. My aim is to copy some files from the CD to the isolated Storage folder on Windows after the installation of my Windows Form Application made with c#.

Comment: You mean `{app}` folder? What is `Isolated Storage Folder`?

Comment: @RobeN, [`Isolated Storage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.110).aspx) is a place for .NET application ("reserved" by its assembly identity). And OP asks how to copy a file to the storage of their application. But I'm afraid except some hardcoded rules finding the physical storage you won't be able to find that folder without creating a bridge library for calling .NET code.

Comment: @TLama so if the `Isolated Storage` is placed as mentioned site states (`<SYSTEMDRIVE>\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming` or `<SYSTEMDRIVE>\Users\<user>\AppData\Local`), then pointing the correct subfolder should do the trick like `{userappdata}\FOLDER_NAME` or `{localappdata}\FOLDER_NAME`. You just have to know the FOLDER_NAME name for this specific application...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!. I decided to copy the files in a application folder into "Roaming " folder, because is really difficult to find the right folder of my app into Isolated Storage.
Thanks to both :)

Comment: @RobeN, but that's the problem. What is described in that reference is just the root folder. The rest of the path (3 subfolders) looks like some encrypted strings and I'm not sure if they remain constant for your application and if they are same on all computers where you run your app. I couldn't find any description of the generated path, just because no one needs to care about it. You have access to your storage from your application and that's all you need. I'm not even sure how would one obtain the path to a foreign application storage, so I'm not even sure if a bridge library would help.

Comment: That's why it's called "**isolated** storage".  Your app can access it.  Other apps (including installers) cannot.